# Does the img tag's alt attribute require encoding?

Tags: html, syntax, encoding, escaping

In html does the text inside the [img tag's alt attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp) require encoding/escaping?

Non encoded example:

```
<img src="myimg.png" alt="image description" />
```

Encoded example:

```
<img src="myimg.png" alt="image%20description" />
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, it does not need to be encoded like a URI.  However, HTML characters must be encoded, like this...

```
<img src="myimg.png" alt="Me &amp; my image" />
```

Comment: Replace "should" with "must" -- at least if you want to pass a validator

Comment: Replace with must if you don't want be caught out putting quotes in there.

Comment: Replace with must if you don't want the yellow screen of death (assuming you are serving your XHTML as application/xhtml+xml, othewise writing XHTML is just more trouble then it  is worth)

Comment: You're right guys.  Sorry about that.  Although with HTML5 on the horizon, I am still not sure how important it is.

Answer (score 5):

They do not require URL encoding, but they do require, as all XHTML attributes do, XHTML entity encoding.

Incorrect:

```
<img src="foo.gif" alt="Ben & Jerry's" />
```

Correct:

```
<img src="foo.gif" alt="Ben &amp; Jerry's" />
```

You would also need to encode double-quotes within the values, even though you don't have to do that in general text.

Reference:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_12

Answer (score 2):

No it does not. Encoding is for URLs as in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dream%20Theater, which the `alt` string is not.

You will need to use [entity-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML#XML_character_entity_references) to escape `>` as `&gt;`, and `"` as `&quot;`, though. Note that that is different from [URI encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_encoding) where special characters are encoded as a percent sign plus two hex digits.

Answer (score -1):

You should use HTML encoding (i.e. " becomes "), not URL encoding.  If you are using ASP.NET you can achieve this with Server.HtmlEncode or better yet use the HtmlAttributeEncode method in the [AntiXSS Library on CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/AntiXSS).