# How to search for special character in a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have tp develop a javascript function with string parameter value which has to search the input parameter contains the following special character like (® ´ © ¿ ¡ ° À & ~ : ? ! # * ^ < > ´ | %). What is best way in javascript to do the above scenario?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there other special characters you need to search for? ☃, 百, etc... How do you define "special character"?

Comment: How would you go about searching for a "normal" character? What breaks with those "special" characters?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer to this in this other post: [Alt attribute encoding with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775328/alt-attribute-encoding-with-javascript)