# jQuery created element not working in IE7

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-7

Using `nickf`'s example found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3137188/1721849)
I've created an element to hack together a replacement for an iframe on a site that is displayed in IE7. It's a short term stop-gap until all the computers at the office are upgraded to IE8 which is why we aren't bothering with a server-side solution.

The goal is to take YouTube embed code and transform it into the old embed code without having to replace every single video on the site.

```
var w = $('iframe').width(),
    h = $('iframe').height(),
    src = $('iframe').attr('src').split('/')[4];

$('iframe').after('<div class="iframediv"></div>');

$('<object></object>', {width: w, height: h})
.append($('<param />', {name: "movie", value: "http://www.youtube.com/v/" + src + "?hl=en_US&amp;version=3"}))
.append($('<param />', {name: "allowFullScreen", value: "true"}))
.append($('<param />', {name: "allowscriptaccess", value: "always"}))
.append($('<embed />', {src: "http://www.youtube.com/v/" + src + "?hl=en_US&amp;version=3", type: "application/x-shockwave-flash", width: w, height: h, allowscriptaccess: "always", allowfullscreen: "true"}))
.appendTo($('.iframediv'));
```

A working example of this code can be found here on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agCje/)

What I'm having trouble with is the created element is not working in IE7. It appears as though the `<object>` creation code is broken and causes jQuery to stop working, yet in Chrome it works perfectly fine. I'm not sure if there is an IE7 specific workaround that I need to accomplish this?

Edit: I purposely left out the line `$('iframe').remove();` for testing purposes for now.

Edit: My fix -

```
if($('html').hasClass('ie7'))
{
    var w = $('iframe').width(),
    h = $('iframe').height(),
    ytsrc = $('iframe').attr('src').split('/')[4];

    $('iframe').after('<div class="iframediv"></div>');
    $('<embed />', {width: w, height: h, src: "http://www.youtube.com/v/" + ytsrc + "?hl=en_US&amp;version=3", type: "application/x-shockwave-flash", allowfullscreen: "true", allowscriptaccess: "always"}).appendTo($('.iframediv'));
    $('iframe').remove();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried creating the `<object>` html as just a single string and appending that?

Comment: I'd suggest creating the object/embed using a single call to `$.parseHTML(htmlstring)`

Comment: Currently working on figuring this one out...still not that familiar with jQuery or Javascript, but thank you both for the suggestions.

Comment: I can't figure out how to get either of those suggestions to work. Is there somewhere specific you can suggest researching this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried creating the  html as just a single string and appending that?

```
$('.iframediv').append('
   <object><param name="move" etc="etc"></param>
   <param stuff="stuff"></param>
   <embed src=""></embed></object>');
```

This is an example. Test with all the correct parameters.

Comment: Thanks Brad M, I ended up getting this yesterday after some trial and error and reading more examples.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem myself. Instead of using like this:

```
$('<div>')
```

to create elements use:

```
$('<div></div>')
```

the second one will work in IE too.